# Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, cryptography

How would I split $n=60112049$ with $B=15$ using Pollard's $p-1$ method.

So I wrote $M=2^3\times3^2\times5\times7\times11\times13$

and set $a=2$.

Then I calculated $a^m \equiv 23763693 \pmod n$, which leads to calculating the $p=\gcd(a^m-1,n)$ as $p=6007$ and noted that $p-1|M$ which is true.

And finally wrote $n=6007\times10007$.

I'm just wondering if all my steps are correct.

Comment: looks good, next step is verifying $6007$ and $10007$s are prime.

Comment: @didgogns : The question doesn't *say* we must factor down to primes.  The question would be improved by indicating whether we must merely find *a* nontrivial factorization or must factor all the way down to primes.